# Java BigInteger Cyclic Group Generator Search

Tags: java, cryptography, biginteger

I'm trying to test for arbitrary generators of a cyclic group. I've found explanations indicating that for a Multliplicative Group Z*p, we want the following conditions to be true:

1. q is a prime number
2. p = 2q + 1 is a prime number
3. p will be used for Z*p

I'm trying to use the following test:

1. If g^2 = 1 mod p, try another number
2. If g^q != 1 mod p try another number
3. Return the number

   ```
   public static BigInteger getGenerator(BigInteger p, BigInteger q){

   BigInteger generator = BigInteger.ZERO;
   BigInteger oneModP = BigInteger.ONE.mod(p);

   for(long i = 2; i < p.intValue()-1; i++)
   {
       generator = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
       if(!generator.pow(2).equals(oneModP)) //if (g^2 = 1 mod p) then go to the next number 
       {
           continue;
       }
       //TODO: make a method that works with BigInteger^BigInteger. This is hackey and limits us to 32 bits
       if(!generator.pow(q.intValue()).equals(oneModP)) //if (g^q != 1modp) then go to the next number
       {
           continue; //next number!
       }
       //TODO: randomly generate then test. Sequential isn't really best here...just for testing purposes
       else
       {
           return generator; //return the first one we find for simplicity's sake
       }
   }


   return generator; }
   ```

However, I'm getting false positives. For example, p=11 (Z*11) it' returning 9 as a generator. Shouldn't it return 2? Thank you for any assistance

Comment: It is concerning that you are passing two parameters to the method and only using one of them. Please post some test code and expected results.

Comment: Hmm...it looks like there's a mistake right there. I can't believe I missed that. It should be !generator.pow(q.intValue()...) in the second if statement. I'll run a test and give anticipated vs actual results shortly

Comment: As an update, I'm still getting 9 as a generator for Z*11 in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here. The first one is already in the textual description: to get an element of order 2q (or do you want an element of order q?) the tests must be:

1. If g^2 = 1 mod p, try another number
2. If g^q = 1 mod p try another number
3. Return the number

The next problem is with the calculation of a^b == 1 (mod p) this should be

```
a.modPow(b, p).equals(BigInteger.ONE)
```

and the if statements do not correspond to the tests because the negation is wrong, use for example

```
if (generator.modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(2), p).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) continue;
```

Comment: Well it certainly doesn't help that I had the concept wrong. I must have gotten something wrong going through my notes. So thank you for pointing out that fundamental problem.

Comment: Your comments seemed to have fixed the problem. It seems part of the issue was trying to learn both BigIntegers AND cyclic groups at the same time. When will I learn!